# Conditional Probability of the null hypothesis given the rejection region

Tags: probability, hypothesis-testing, distributions, mathematical-statistics

let $X  \sim Bin(10,p)$

We would like to test the following hypotheses:

$H_{0}: p=0.5 $ vs $H_{1} : p=0.3$

The Statistic $T(x)$ is defined as $T(x)=x$ and the critical (rejection) region is  $R=\{x:T(x)\le4\}$

I want to calculate the conditional probability of the null hypothesis given $T(x)\in R $

That is : $P(H_{0}\mid  T(x)\in R)$

**My first solution is:** $P(H_{0}\mid  T(x)\in R)=\frac{\alpha}{1-\beta}$

**My second solution** (according to Bayesian hypothesis):

$P(H_{0}\mid  T(x)\in R) = P(H_{0})*L(H_{0}\mid T(x)\in R)$ , which is equal to :

$P(H_{0}\mid  T(x)\in R) = P(H_{0})*P(T(x)\in R\mid H_{0})$

$P(T(x)\in R\mid H_{0})= P_{H_{0}}(X\le4)=0.37695=\alpha$

while $P(H_{0})$ equal to :

$ P(H_{0})= P(H_{0}\mid T(x)\notin R) + P(H_{0}\mid T(x)\in R)=\frac{1-\alpha}{\beta} +\frac{\alpha}{1-\beta} $

Thus: $P(H_{0}\mid  T(x)\in R)=(\frac{1-\alpha}{\beta} +\frac{\alpha}{1-\beta})*\alpha$

**Which of the above solutions is correct ?**

Comment: None of these is correct.  Unless you have a prior probability to update, $P(H_0|T(x)\in R)$ is not even meaningful.

Comment: Thanks, its a homework question ... given that I am in the rejection region what is the probability that  $H_{0}$ is true ( Or on other words the probability that the  statistics fall in the rejection coming from $H_{0}$ and not from $H_{1}$

Answer (score 1):

When we write the probability for the type I error, we write
$P(T(x) \leq 4 | H_0) = \ldots$

But it is not a conditional probability, it is just an abuse of notation, or if you prefer, it is just a short form of expressing the following:
*Let's assume $H_0$ is valid. Under this assumption, let's calculate

$P(T(x) \leq 4 ) = \ldots$*

It is not a conditional probability in the sense, that it cannot be rewritten as
$P(T(x) \leq 4 | H_0) = \frac{P(T(x) \leq 4 \cap H_0)}{P(H_0)}$, because there is no notion of $P(H_0)$, or no prior probability, as summarized by Thomas Lumley.

So, there is no sense of considering $P(H_0 | T(x) \leq 4)$, either.

Comment: Hi Thank you ... its just the probability that I fall in the rejection region coming from the null hypothesis.

Comment: its a homework question ... given that I am in the rejection region what is the probability that H0 is true ( Or on other words the probability that the statistics fall in the rejection coming from H0 and not from H1)

Comment: Building upon your "Or on other words..." version: maybe the question is "what is the probability of falling into the rejection region if $H_0$ is true?". If it were the question, then you would want to calculate $P(X \leq 4)$ assuming that probability of a single success in your binomial distribution is $p=0.5$.

Comment: @Solomon123: it's not possible to compute a posterior probability for $H_0$ without a prior probability. Is there a prior probability you didn't tell us about?